# Rails - nested model inside devise model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have two models which is Members and Company...
Members is the devise model... When I sign up I want to include the following fields in the signup form.

1. Name
2. Email address
3. Password
4. Company name (from Company model)
5. company type (from Company model)

> Member has one company

I am trying to create the signup form via nested form.. But I am not sure to build the form for the Company to receive input from the user...

Here is my controller

```
class Brands::Members::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
# before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    @company = Company.new
    super
  end

  # POST /resource
  def create
    @company = Company.new(configure_sign_up_params)
    @company.valid?

    super
  end
end
```

Here is my View

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <!--
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>
  -->
<%= @company.errors %>
  <%= fields_for @company do |fc| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= fc.label :name %><br />
      <%= fc.text_field :name %>
    </div>

  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "brands/members/shared/links" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help,

Change your new action to this

```
@member = Member.new
@member.build_company
```